# Does iOS have any equivalents to DLLs/IPC/process spawning?

Tags: ios

1. Are separate apps able to share the same binary in a form like a DLL? I know its possible to compile static libraries but I wouldn't count these as the same as a DLL (i.e. a dll is one copy of a binary shared by multiple apps, whereas static libraries are separately included by any using app).
2. Is each app totally separate from each other, are there any IPC or file sharing mechanisms available for differing apps to communicate and share data?
3. Is it possible for an app to create a new process in addition to a new thread (I guess not)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't share executable files between applications. Apple requires that all apps function standalone. However you can use a UIDocumentInteractionController to get another program to deal with files you don't understand, and a 'quick view' may be available. That's how Mail works, for example.

Programs from the same vendor can share the keychain and, I think, iCloud storage as of iOS 5, but can't share storage on disk. As they can declare supported file types, UIDocumentInteractionController can be used to push temporary access to a file from one app to another. A custom URL scheme can be used in a similar way to pass fragments of data if that helps.

As a general rule, only one user process may be active at once in iOS - e.g. background processing is essentially event based. So you can't create a second process for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can do this if you are developing for a jailbroken phone. Not
   otherwise.On jailbroken phones, you can create .dylibs or shared libraries that can be
   loaded via the `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` environment var (much like on
   MacOS)
2. Apps are sandboxed. However, there are some ways of communicating between apps. You can use

   (a) [customURL scheme (also mentioned by Tommy above)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)
       (if any) associated with an app to launch an app and send some
       parameters to the launching app

   (b) If you control communicating
       apps, [then you can use Message ports (CFMessagePortCreateRemote)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMessagePortRef/Reference/reference.html)

   (c) If you control communicating apps, [you could use Darwin
       NOtification center for distributed apps.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/Reference/reference.html)

   Of course the expectation for (b) and (c) is that the
   communicating apps are all running. On iOS since there is only one foreground
   process, you'd have to have the other as a background app and that's
   restricted to certain kinds of apps on the iOS platform.

Comment: CFMessagePort is not available since iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no to all of the above, unless you're targeting jailbroken phones and are bypassing Apple's App Store. If you jailbreak, I believe you have similar options to those you have in Mac OS X.

Comment: Thankyou. With regards to 2) - different classes within an app can use NSNotificationCenter to communicate with each other, can NSNotificationCenter also be used between two apps?