# is there a loopback interface in iOS (iPad, iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, loopback

1. is there a loopback interface in iOS (iPad, iPhone)?
2. And if yes, can it be used to securely communicate between two applications/threads within iOS?
3. Will any other application run iOS can snoop and it data traffic over loopback interface between two applications?

Comment: Attention close voters: this isn't asking for a library recommendation.

Comment: This is perfectly valid question IMO since it asks about availability of a darwin API which is otherwise available on non-iOS environments.

Answer (score 4):

1. [No](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/lo.4.html) -- [`lo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/lo.4.html) isn't available in the iOS Darwin tools.
2. N/A
3. N/A

If you're looking to have two applications communicate securely, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10607939/68507) has a few different solutions which might suit you.

Comment: thanks, in that case how will an UIWebview based App communicate its Websocket server running in background as a thread ?

Comment: You would have to add a layer in the app that implements `UIWebViewDelegate` and does the required work. Likely in the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method.

Comment: thank you so much, another related question: is it possible of any other App on iOS be able to snoop the websocket traffic between app (i.e UIWebView based client )  with its background websocket server thread ?  Note:  All these apps and services are running locally on the same iOS device.

Comment: You should consider asking that as a separate question, @user2548414. Others might benefit from the answer...

Comment: ok, posted the above websocket data traffic snooping as separate question.

Comment: I found that an iOS App which has some components of it written in  native C/C++ code can access loopback address 127.0.0.1 and use it for exchanging data between threads/processes within iOS device.

Comment: @user2548414 What library did you have to link against to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I see the thread is quite old and realize things may have changed, but I thought I'd share what I've found on my phone.
The reason I'm here was because I was thinking my **`"unhackable"`** Apple device had been hacked.  Still working on this.
  But here's a list of my interfaces.

```
Ap1,  awdl0,  en0,  en1,  lo0,<==  pdp_ip0,  pdp_ip1,  pdp_ip2
```

And it's running, not sure if I misunderstood that one may be available in general just not running Darwin. But in either case I am running Darwin.